# Cant' make nav display next to h1 element

Tags: html, css, floating

***solved - it was a group effort. thank you all so much, my first posting experience on here was wonderful and you all have given me things to learn :)***

I am trying to make a site using html5/css(3). I want to have a  nav bar to be at the far end of the header, and to be on the same line as the h1 element while sharing the h1 background. (if possible)
I will post the code I am using, plus a screenshot showing what it looks like vs what I want it to look like.
***note*** I have been messing around with this for several hours so my code is pretty...all over the place right now. Sorry.

LINK TO THE IMAGE: http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e50/Fallon_Vii/screencap.png

```
<body id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<img src="images/logo2.png">
<h2>Broadcast Services</h2>

<ul id="nav">
<li class="border"> <a href="index.hmtl">Home</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="about.hmtl">PAGE 2</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="master.hmtl">PAGE 3</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="advertise.hmtl">PAGE 4</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="entertainment.hmtl">PAGE 5</a></li>
<li> <a href="contact.hmtl">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

```
#header {
width: 100%;
border-top: 1.5px solid black;
border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
margin-bottom: 4%;
padding: .75%;
}

#header img {
width: 30%;
display: inline;
}

h2 {
color: #4F2F8F;
font-size: 125%;
font-weight: bold;
background-image: url(images/transpblack10.png);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
line-height: 85%;
}

#nav  {
font-size: 110%;
float: right;
}

#nav ul li {
display: inline;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off you don't have the proper syntax for your `<ul>`'s... it should look like this:

```
ul#nav li {
display: inline;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul#nav li a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

And I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQVLy/5/

Comment: aah, thank-you. I didn't realize I needed to put it like that. Now it looks like this: http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e50/Fallon_Vii/screencap-1.png    I will keep messing around with it unless someone knows what else to do. :)

Comment: I added a jsFiddle with your solution

Comment: Updated the fiddle again so the nav appears low and not high. Just play with the margin til you get what you want.

Comment: Another way to fix this, and automatically placing the `<ul>` in the right spot, would be to swap the `<ul>` and the `<h2>` in your HTML around, and setting the `<ul>` to e.g. 70% width and the  `<h2>` to 30% width.

Comment: Tommy Coffee, I adjusted to your specs (wothout the top paggind) and added float: left to the header div, and it is closer, this is what it's looking like now: http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e50/Fallon_Vii/screencap-2.png     @user1846192 I will give that a try now!

Comment: @AllisonMcKillop so what exactly are you trying to achieve? I thought this is what you wanted.

Comment: You just need to play with the margin so it aligns correctly with your H2.

Comment: @user1846192, I am trying your approach out now, it's late so I am slow at making changes, my apologies. Tommy Coffee, what you gave me was very very close, but the nav was still a line lower and didn't share the grey background. (if that's even possible to do) Unless I am missing something, which is entirely possible at this hour. Thank you everyone for your patience and help

Comment: I think @TommyCoffee's has a point, if you use his approach and change the top padding on the `<ul>`, you should be able to make the menu line up. I do wonder why the grey background of the `<h2>` doesn't run all the way to the right on your latest screenshot. If you want the grey background to run all the way behind the menu using my approach, you would have to set the background of the  `<ul>` to be that same background image.

Comment: @AllisonMcKillop I see you wrote that your problem was solved. please make sure you check this answer as your solution.

Comment: And just a little extra thing I noticed, your filename extensions are .hMtl. This might give you some issue navigating later on..

Answer (score -1):

Hi Allison please check it the mentioned below code its working fine as per your requirement....

Actually you made some minor mistakes that's why it was coming so messy now i have sorted the errors and its working so you can check....

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NQVLy/11/)**

**HTML**

```
<body id="wrapper">
<div id="header">

 <div class="bg">
<img src="images/logo2.png">
<h2>Broadcast Services</h2>
<ul id="nav">
<li class="border"> <a href="index.hmtl">Home</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="about.hmtl">PAGE 2</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="master.hmtl">PAGE 3</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="advertise.hmtl">PAGE 4</a></li>
<li class="border"> <a href="entertainment.hmtl">PAGE 5</a></li>
<li> <a href="contact.hmtl">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
width: 100%;
border-top: 1.5px solid black;
border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
margin-bottom: 4%;
padding: .75%;
}

#header img {
width: 30%;
display: inline;
}
.bg {
    background:grey;
}
h2 {
color: #4F2F8F;
font-size: 125%;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav  {
font-size: 110%;
float: right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
```